# ElasticSearch (with NEST) search in multiple fields

Tags: search, elasticsearch, nest

I just want to search "searchText" in two properties of the class (Id and RoundTemplateName).

```
.Query(q =>
   q.Term(f => f.Id, searchText)
   || q.Term(f => f.RoundTemplateName, searchText)
```

What is wrong with the query? It only searchs in Id property...

Thank you in advance,
Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this would be using a multi_match query
In the below example the query will be run against both fields (subject & message)

```
{
    "multi_match" : {
    "query":    "this is a test", 
    "fields": [ "subject", "message" ] 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That query looks good, you can inspect the query it generates by printing `result.ConnectionStatus.ToString()`.

You can also use the `Terms()` query

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-query/